# @ReservedStackAccess what does it mean a method especially sensitive to stack overflows

Tags: java

The following is javadoc for @ReservedStackAccess

> An annotation expressing that a method is especially sensitive to stack overflows. This is a hint the JVM can use to grant access to extra stack space when executing this code if such feature is supported by the JVM. The JVM is free to ignore this annotation. A possible way for the JVM to improve the execution context for methods with this annotation is to reserve part of the thread's execution stack for them. Access to this section of the stack would be denied by default but could be granted if the JVM detects a possible stack overflow and the thread's call stack includes at least one annotated method. Even if access to this reserved area has been granted, the JVM might decide to throw a delayed StackOverflowError when the thread exits the annotated method.
> Since:
> 9

What does it mean "a method is especially sensitive to stack overflows."? Is there a method that is not sensitive toward that? What kind of method is espeically sensitive to stack overflows? Can I define my own sensitive method and use that annotation?

EDIT: to make my question more specific, the following is a method from StampedLock class, it has such an annotation.

```
    /**
     * Exclusively acquires the lock, blocking if necessary
     * until available.
     *
     * @return a write stamp that can be used to unlock or convert mode
     */
    @ReservedStackAccess
    public long writeLock() {
        long next;
        return ((next = tryWriteLock()) != 0L) ? next : acquireWrite(false, 0L);
    }
```

Comment: "Is there a method that is not sensitive toward that?" Trivially, methods that don't call other methods are not sensitive to stack overflows.

Comment: @Sweeper what you describe is a method that is unlikely to result in a stack overflow. Surely, being _prone_ to stack overflow is different from being _sensitive_ to it. I would define being sensitive to stack overflow to mean something terrible will happen if a stack overflow occurs, whereas methods that are not sensitive to stack overflow will allow the application to recover gracefully from a stack overflow.

Comment: From the following javadoc, I guess a "sensitive" method is a method that may consume a not-predefined or not-estimated  amount of stack. Like a method that requires C malloc.